# largest proportion of the values $x_i$ that lie outside ...with $X$ uniformly distributed

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X$ is uniformly distributed in $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$. What is the largest proportion of the values $x_i$ that can lie outside $(\bar X - 2\sigma^2_X, \bar X + 2\sigma^2_X)$, where
$$\bar x = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ 
and
$$\sigma^2_X = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2$$

I completely blanked out on this question on my test...

Answer (score 1):

WLOG let $\bar x=0$. The proportion of $x_i$ outside $2\sigma$ occurs with all the $x_i$ either $0$ or $\pm 2\sigma$. Then $\displaystyle\sigma^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i^2}n=\frac{4\sigma^2k}{n}$ where $k$ is the number of $x_i=\pm 2\sigma$. Then the required proportion  $\displaystyle\frac{k}{n}=\frac{1}4$.